# Generic function for dynamic casting base class to child class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, dynamic-cast

I am working on a C++ project and I have a base class A which can have many derived classes like B, C, and so on.

I want to write a generic function for dynamic base class to whatever child class if possible. So I wrote the following function:

```
template<typename T>
optional<T> A::get_if_convertible()
{
    optional<T> return_val = none;
    using converted_ptr_type = typename std::add_pointer<T>::type;
    auto ptr = dynamic_cast<converted_ptr_type>(this);
    if (ptr)
        return_val = dynamic_cast<T>(ptr);
    return return_val;
}
```

What I need is if `this` is a pointer to a `const` object then my returned derived class object should also be `const`. Is this the correct way for dynamic casting? How to handle the case if `this` is a pointer to a `const` object?

Comment: Do you want object slicing? why `std::optional` whereas `dynamic_cast` (with pointer) might already return `nullptr` when cast doesn't match.

Comment: I actually want client to either get concrete(derived) object or not. So optional seems better choice. Suppose I have const A*. If it points to type B, then type B object should be returned(not sliced) and its constness should be maintained. Also get_if_convertible() is my internal function, client will call function such as - optional get_B();

Comment: Apart from the facts that this is not valid C++ and that your (pseudocode) function _always_ returns `none`, I don't see how this interface provides any additional value compared to a raw `dynamic_cast`. If you have a pointer `const A* p`, then `dynamic_cast<B const*>(p)` gives you a pointer of type `const B*`. This pointer will either point to an actual `B` object (if `p` points to a `B` object) or be `nullptr` (if `p` does not point to a `B` object). So `dynamic_cast` already preserves constness.

Comment: As you're returning a copy of the object anyway does the `const` even matter?

Comment: There is no way to tell whether `this` is really a pointer to a const object or a const pointer to a non-const object, and returning a const object is pretty pointless. This looks a lot like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what is your ultimate goal?

Comment: Thanks. looks like there is no way I can return concrete type of derived class and should return pointer only. My goal is to to provide the client a generic utility function to downcast base object into client's provided derived type.

Comment: Also, is returning nullptr if operation fails is more error prone(client can mistakenly derefernce nullptr)? should one return an empty optional object or nullptr if operation fails?

Comment: Dereferencing the unset optional will be just as undefined as dereferencing a null pointer. Ah optional pointer doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments from experts in the question, I implemented the following generic function:

```
template <typename T>
T* A::get_if_convertible() {
    return dynamic_cast<T*>(this);
}

template <typename T>
const T* A::get_if_convertible() const {
    return dynamic_cast<const T*>(this);
}
```

The client can simply write the following code and appropriate `fun()` version will be called:

```
void fun(const B* b);
    
void fun(B* b);

int main()
{
    auto ptr_A = get_A_ptr();
    fun(ptr_A->get_if_convertible<B>());
}
```

Thank you all for the help.